# View Pager inside Recycler view not showing the data in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I need to make a ecommerce app type screen with multiple viewpager and recycler views.

I implemented it but my 1 out of 2 view pager is visible in recycler view and once I rotate the device, my first view pager also disappear.

My Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private List<ProductEntity> productEntities = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView productlist;
private HomeAdapter homeAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    productlist = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.mainlist);
    //productlist.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    productlist.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    homeAdapter = new HomeAdapter(this,getSupportFragmentManager(),productEntities);
    productlist.setAdapter(homeAdapter);
    new ParserJsonTask().execute();
}

public  String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(
                "f_two.json")));
        String temp;
        while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(temp);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close(); // stop reading
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

private class ParserJsonTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, List<ProductEntity>> {
    @Override
    protected List<ProductEntity> doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try{
            return JsonParser.getInstance().parseJson(loadJSONFromAsset());

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<ProductEntity> result) {
        Log.e("Length",""+result.size());
        if(result != null) {
            productEntities = result;
            homeAdapter.setProduct(productEntities);
        }
    }
}
```

My view pager Fragment:

```
public class ImageFragment extends Fragment {
/**
 * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
 * fragment.
 */
private static final String ARG_IMAGE_URL = "image_url";
private Context context;
private String image_url;
public ImageFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.context = context;
}

/**
 * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
 * number.
 */
public static ImageFragment newInstance(String image) {
    ImageFragment fragment = new ImageFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_IMAGE_URL, image);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        image_url = getArguments().getString(ARG_IMAGE_URL);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image, container, false);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    Log.e("Pager Item Image",""+image_url);
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(image_url))
    Picasso.with(context).load(image_url).into(image);
    return rootView;
}
}
```

My Main adapter for recycler view:

```
public class HomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private List<ProductEntity> productEntities;
private Context context;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;
private static final int TYPE_FIRST = 0;
private static final int TYPE_SECOND = 1;
private static final int TYPE_THIRD = 2;
private static final String TEMPLATE_FIRST ="product-template-1";
private static final String TEMPLATE_SECOND ="product-template-2";
private static final String TEMPLATE_THIRD ="product-template-3";
public HomeAdapter(Context context , FragmentManager fragmentManager ,List<ProductEntity> productEntities) {
    this.productEntities = productEntities;
    this.context = context;
    this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.e("Item count",""+productEntities.size());
    return productEntities.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(holder instanceof ImageViewHolder) {
        ImageViewHolder imageViewHolder = (ImageViewHolder) holder;
        ProductEntity productEntity = productEntities.get(position);
        Log.e("Template Item Image",""+productEntity.getItemEntities().get(0).getImage());
        Picasso.with(context).load(productEntity.getItemEntities().get(0).getImage()).into(imageViewHolder.imageView);
    } else if(holder instanceof PagerViewHolder) {
        PagerViewHolder pagerViewHolder = (PagerViewHolder) holder;
        ProductEntity productEntity = productEntities.get(position);
        pagerViewHolder.viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(fragmentManager,productEntity.getItemEntities()));
    } else if (holder instanceof HorizontalViewHolder) {
        HorizontalViewHolder horizontalViewHolder = (HorizontalViewHolder) holder;
        ProductEntity productEntity = productEntities.get(position);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        horizontalViewHolder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        horizontalViewHolder.recyclerView.setAdapter(new SliderAdapter(context,productEntity.getItemEntities()));
    }

}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder (ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     if(viewType == TYPE_FIRST) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext ()).inflate (R.layout.content_image, parent, false);
        return new ImageViewHolder (v);
    } else if(viewType == TYPE_SECOND) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext ()).inflate (R.layout.content_horizontal, parent, false);
        return new HorizontalViewHolder (v);
    } else {
         View v = LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext ()).inflate (R.layout.content_pager, parent, false);
         return new PagerViewHolder(v);
     }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType (int position) {
    if(productEntities.get(position).getTemplate().equalsIgnoreCase(TEMPLATE_FIRST)) {
        Log.e("Item type",""+TYPE_FIRST);
        return TYPE_FIRST;
    } else if(productEntities.get(position).getTemplate().equalsIgnoreCase(TEMPLATE_SECOND)) {
        Log.e("Item type",""+TYPE_SECOND);
        return TYPE_SECOND;
    } else {
        Log.e("Item type",""+TYPE_THIRD);
        return TYPE_THIRD;
    }
}

class PagerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected ViewPager viewPager;

    public PagerViewHolder (View itemView) {
        super (itemView);
        this.viewPager = (ViewPager) itemView.findViewById (R.id.viewpager);
    }
}

class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected ImageView imageView;

    public ImageViewHolder (View itemView) {
        super (itemView);
        this.imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById (R.id.image);
    }
}

public  class HorizontalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public HorizontalViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.horizontallist);
    }
}

public void setProduct(List<ProductEntity> data) {
    productEntities.clear();
    productEntities.addAll(data);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}

public void SetOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
    this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
}
}
```

My view pager adapter:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private List<ItemEntity> itemEntities;
public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<ItemEntity> itemEntities) {
    super(fm);
    this.itemEntities = itemEntities;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
    // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
    return ImageFragment.newInstance(itemEntities.get(position).getImage());
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // Show 3 total pages.
    return itemEntities.size();
}
}
```

My horizontal recyclerview adapter:

```
public class SliderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private List<ItemEntity> itemEntities;
private Context context;
private OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;
public SliderAdapter(Context context , List<ItemEntity> notesEntities) {
    this.itemEntities = notesEntities;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return itemEntities.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder = (ItemViewHolder) holder;
        ItemEntity itemEntity = itemEntities.get(position);
        itemViewHolder.productName.setText(itemEntity.getLabel());
        Log.e("Item Image",""+itemEntity.getImage());
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(itemEntity.getImage()))
        Picasso.with(context).load(itemEntity.getImage()).into(itemViewHolder.productImage);
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder (ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext ()).inflate (R.layout.recycler_card_layout, parent, false);
        return new ItemViewHolder (v);

}

public  class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected TextView productName;
    protected ImageView productImage;

    public ItemViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        productName =  (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
        productImage = (ImageView)  v.findViewById(R.id.product_image);

        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mItemClickListener != null)
                    mItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });

    }
}

public void setItems(List<ItemEntity> data) {
    itemEntities.clear();
    itemEntities.addAll(data);
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}

public void SetOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
    this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
}

}
```

Main activity layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".activity.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/mainlist"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Horizontal scrolling layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".activity.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/horizontallist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

View pager layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

As per my JSON data, it should have 2 view pager inside recycler view and but      it is showing only 1 in portrait mode and once I rotate the device, both are disappear. I thing data is not visible inside recycler view as I can see white space in recycler view while scrolling.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Found any solution on this?

Comment: Yes 

I solved this issue by assigning dynamic Id to view pager. view pager can't have same Id so i need to dynamically add the ID.

this.viewPager.setId(Id++);

Comment: hii @SandeepAgrawal, can you help me!
if you can guide me or provide some demo code. thank you in advance.
I need to have an ViewPager inside an RecyclerView(similar to new instagram feature), Each row of the RecyclerView will have an ViewPager which will allow to swipe between some images or video. 
Note: viewpager with fragments.

Comment: Please download the sample code from https://github.com/sandeep-agrawal/RecyclerView-and-View-Pager

Answer (score -2):

Simple change :

```
extends FragmentPagerAdapter
```

to

```
extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
```